# div line doesnt show up correctly ie6 floated left

Tags: css-float

I have a similar problem to this question [Why does my floated left div go to the next line in IE6 using the 960.gs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200731/why-does-my-floated-left-div-go-to-the-next-line-in-ie6-using-the-960-gs)

In my design, the subcategories should be 4 per row.  They look fine in FF,Safari,Chrome, but in ie6 they only show 3 per row. I tried creating a different css for ie6, but it didnt work, also i tried reducing the width and padding of each row, but still i have 3 subcategories per row.

I asked again because i bet the solution can be very specific to the css you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try setting width of each .subcategory at 24% or max 237px

```
.subcategory
{
    width:24%;
}
```

**updated**

in category.css change in this way:

```
.subcategory {
    FLOAT: left; MARGIN-BOTTOM: 15px; WIDTH: 24%; HEIGHT: 230px; TEXT-ALIGN: center
}
.category-item-image {
DISPLAY: block; BACKGROUND: #fff; MARGIN: 5px 30px; WIDTH: 170px; PADDING-TOP: 5px;            HEIGHT: 170px; oveflow: hidden
}
 .subcategory-image {
DISPLAY: block; BACKGROUND: #fff; MARGIN: 5px 30px; WIDTH: 170px; PADDING-TOP: 5px; HEIGHT: 170px; oveflow: hidden
}
```

Problems are

```
MARGIN: 5px 34px;
```

and

```
WIDTH: 25%;
```

I've tried to set them at 30px and 24% and in IE6 it works!

Comment: oh! I read now IE6!! Microsoft no more supports IE6 at all! Statistics tells that today only 2.5% use IE6 (http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_explorer.asp). Are you sure you need to support it? In IE9 and in "compatibility mode" it works with 24%.

Comment: i know that, but the people i am working asked for that and paid extra for that.  They wanted support for ie6, i hate that thing